# How to catch "throws Exeception" without using try catch block?

Tags: java, design-patterns, try-catch

I have a base class which implements the following interface, the methods declared on it throw the basic exception type `Exception`.

There are many concrete classes extending the base class and **i dont want to add a `try-catch` block** in all of them. Is there a way to handle `throws` without adding `try-catch`?

**Interface**

```
public interface IReportFactory {   
    public Object GetDataFromDB(Connection conn,HashMap<String,String> map) throws  Exception;        
    public Object  GetJSONString(HashMap<String,String> map) throws Exception;
}
```

**Base class**

```
public abstract class BaseReport implements IReportFactory{        
    public Connection conn;
    public String acctId = FactoryReport.getAcctId();


    ------ I WANT TO CATCH EXCEPTION HERE    ------
    ------ WHICH ACCURS IN OTHER CLASSES WHICH EXTENDS FROM THIS CLASSES -----


}
```

**Example of a concrete class (there are 30)**

```
public class GeneralRevenue extends BaseReport {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GeneralRevenue.class);

     public GeneralRevenue(Connection _conn) {  
        this.conn = _conn;
    }

    @Override
    public Object GetJSONString(HashMap<String,String> params) throws Exception {

        //codes 
        return jObj.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object GetDataFromDB(Connection conn,HashMap params) throws Exception {

        //codes 
        return RevenueList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you're extending the interface doesn't mean you have to add `throws Exception`, it's ok to declare your implementing class as throwing less exceptions than the interface. You just can't make the implementation throw broader exceptions than the interface.

So you could define your methods without the throws clause, like:

```
public Object GetJSONString(HashMap<String,String> params) {
```

and if there is any checked exception thrown you can rethrow it as an unchecked exception.

If you want to catch exceptions thrown by the subclass, you have to rearrange your code so that methods of the subclass are called by the super class, otherwise the super class doesn't have the opportunity to catch anything. You might consider if it makes sense to use strategies (which would let you wrap the calls to the strategies and might reduce the amount of inheritance you have to do).

Something that happens a lot is that developers use inheritance as their preferred means of extension, and (since we're always in a hurry) there's not a lot of thought about keeping concerns separated, with the result being code that's complicated and inflexible. Breaking this up along different lines of responsibility might help to make this less complicated and would probably help with the exception-throwing situation, since the different pieces would be better-focused and could throw less broad exceptions.

Comment: This code has been written before me, and all concreate classes' methods have throws exception. Are there a way to handle all exception in baseclass without adding try catch all concreate classes' methods ? For example, can i catch exception which accurs in concreate class, in baseclass ?

Comment: And all classes methods must throws exception, but i should handle them in baseclass. I am asking about this, i hope i can explain my problem

Comment: @talhakosen: yes, you can catch whatever in the concrete class and handle it there. You're not required to throw anything.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer ! please look at my question, how can i catch an exception which accurs in GeneralReveneu classes' GetJSONString methods, in baseclass ?

Comment: @talhakosen: wondered if that was part of this, wasn't sure. No, the base class can't catch the subclass's exceptions. If you reworked things to use strategies instead of subclasses then the exceptions thrown by a strategy could be handled by the caller of the strategy. (or, likewise, rearrange things so something done by subclass is called by the superclass)

Comment: I see, i think i have to rewrite :)

Comment: @talhakosen: that would make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom **RuntimeException** and throw it inside the try catch block of your base class?

```
public class GeneralRevenue extends BaseReport {
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GeneralRevenue.class);


 public GeneralRevenue(Connection _conn) {  
    this.conn = _conn;
}

@Override
public Object GetJSONString(HashMap<String,String> params) throws MyException {
    try{
    //codes 
    }catch(Exception e) {
     throw new MyException();
    }


    return jObj.toString();
}
}

class MyException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you throw RuntimeException then there is no need to add the throws declaration. So for Example of you create your own RuntimeException like

```
 class NewException extends RuntimeException{

  }
```

Then when you add RuntimeException to your BaseClass all the other methods will not have to declare throws which will call these methods.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html